# Small program to quickly set window size, for consistent screenshots for help files, websites, etc.?

Tags: windows, window

I know I've seen this somewhere but I can't remember where I found it or what the name was.

I am creating a help file for an internal application and would like to take screenshots of various windows, but I'd like to make them all the same size, for consistency.

Is there a program that can resize another program to specific sizes? The program I remember had a dropdown for various screen sizes, like 800x600, 1024x768, etc. but also manually typing in a size.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Since this was for writing help files I assumed this is a good site to ask on, if it should be on superuser instead (since it isn't strictly a programming question), just let me know and I'll migrate it.

Comment: @Arjan: You are right on both accounts. The other explicitly mentioned ***not* just firefox*, while it was implicit here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Programs  **[Sizer](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer/)** or **[AutoSizer](http://www.southbaypc.com/autosizer/)**

For Screenshots : 
[Snagit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SnagIt) or its [Alternatives like Greenshot etc](http://alternativeto.net/software/snagit/)

Comment: How do I set the size of my program window with Snagit? I can't seem to find that function.

Comment: Are you maybe looking at the problem in reverse? Instead of setting the size of the program window you would need to set the capture size or you can re size/preset the captured image. You can find detailed instructions at [snagit learning center](http://www.techsmith.com/learn/snagit/) more specifically at the [Snagit Capture tutorial](http://www.techsmith.com/learn/snagit/capture/default.asp)

Comment: I don't want to resize an image taken at resolution 807x733 to 640x480, I need the program window to actually be 640x480 before capturing. Can Snagit do that? I've found an "Extended area" setting, but unfortunately it turns of "actual caption", ie. the glass effect, and doesn't capture the mouse. I know I've seen a program that simply resized a window to be an exact size for me, so I'll keep hunting for that.